# Which resultset to use for image in fmdb?

Tags: sqlite, swift3, fmdb

Which FMDB resultset use to retrieve image from database. FMResultSet has many methods to retrieve data in an appropriate format:

- intForColumn:
- longForColumn:
- longLongIntForColumn:
- boolForColumn:
- doubleForColumn:
- stringForColumn:
- dateForColumn:
- dataForColumn:
- dataNoCopyForColumn:
- UTF8StringForColumnIndex:
- objectForColumn:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save and retrieve images and videos in sqlite using FMDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31085249/608639)

Comment: @sapna You can use `stringForColumn` for retrieve images.

Comment: but Image is save as blob in db browser so how can i user stringforcolumn@KetanOdedra

Comment: @sapna 
`let imageBytes = "" // blob data
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let imgData = imageBytes.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
    }
}`